# Turtles not reseting under a conditional

Tags: netlogo

I'm trying to have turtles match based on attraction parameters, however I only get either one match or one mismatch and won't count anymore turtles matching, as well as not moving the counter forward.

```
to new-couple
 set countdown2 5
 ask turtles [
 ;; CREATE NEW COUPLE
 ifelse countdown2 <= 0
    [ die ]
    [ set countdown2 countdown2 - 1 ] ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The code that you have provided does not have an error. Try this version of it and you will see that the new-couple code correctly reduces the countdown 5 times and then kills the rest of the turtles. So it's not producing the problem that you describe of things only happening once.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  type "Start turtles: " print count turtles
  new-couple
  type "End turtles: " print count turtles
end

to new-couple
 let countdown2 5
 ask turtles [
 ;; CREATE NEW COUPLE
 ifelse countdown2 <= 0
    [ die ]
    [ set countdown2 countdown2 - 1 ] ]
end
```

Could you please provide more of your code. Also, an explanation of what the countdown is supposed to achieve could be useful. At the moment it basically selects the number of turtles that don't die and there are easier ways to achieve that.